# Minimal solution to a linear Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I solved many linear diophantine equation, but i found some exercises where, in addition to find the general solution of the equation, i have to find the *minimal solutions* of it.
I've found a similar question, but still it's not totally clear to me.

For example i'm considering this linear diophantine equation:

$ 12x + 20y = 5528 $

General Solution:

$ x' = 2764 +5k \hspace{1cm}  y' = -1382 -3k $ $\hspace{1cm} k\in \mathbb{Z}$

I thought that i can find the minimal solutions finding the smallest $k$.
I also read an answer here [How can we find the minimal solutions to a linear Diophantine equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3446084/how-can-we-find-the-minimal-solutions-to-a-linear-diophantine-equation) where the user "A.J." says that

> *"To find the minimal solution to $ ax+by=n $, we simply need to find $k$ such that $nx′−kb$ and $ny′+ka$ are as close as possible"*

So, to find the minimal solutions like in the answer of the post i mentioned above i sould put  $x'$ equal to $y'$, that in my case is  $ 2764 +5k = -1382 -3k $ so that i can obtain a value of $k$ that will determine my minimal solutions.

I would like to know how would you answer this question and i would really appreciate an explanation or some advices for this type of excersise.

Comment: Please define "minimal solution".

Comment: Per the comment of @BillDubuque, if you have an equation like $Ax - By = C$, and $x,y$ is restricted to $\Bbb{Z^+}$, the the concept of "*minimal solution*" seems reasonable.  That is, in my example, as $x$ increases, $y$ increases.  Your example has two problems: [1] The specification (instead) resembles $Ax + By = \cdots$ [2] You have not mentioned whether $x,y$ may be negative.  Therefore, for your problem, you must explicitly define *minimal solution* **unambiguously**.

Comment: @BillDubuque For example: Given $12x + 20y=5528$, $x$ represent the number of boxes whose weight is $12kg$ and $y$ the number of boxes of $20kg$. I have to put the boxes in a container that has a max payload of $5528kg$. What is the way to do this by using the minimum number of boxes in total?

Comment: So, you are defining *minimal solution* to represent that $x,y$ must each be non-negative integers, and that you want to minimize the sum $(x + y)$.  Is this correct?

Comment: @user2661923 Exactly

Comment: Then, identify the minimum and maximum values for $k$ such that $x,y$ are both non-negative integers.  Then, express the sum to be minimized, $(x+y)$ as a function in $k$ : $f(k)$.  Then, you should be able to identify $k$ by examining the minimum and maximum allowable values of $k$.  Note that it seems clear that $f'(k)$ will either always be positive, or always be negative.  If either assertion on $f'(k)$ is true, then the minimum sum will **have** to be achieved at one of the endpoints of the allowable range for $k$.